# Is there way to create a swagger doc for latest version api?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger

I use dotnet tool called "swagger" to create a swagger json file that contains API spec for specific version.
Command be like:
`swagger tofile --serializeasv2 --output rest-api.json C:\Service.dll v1`

As you can see I have to pass swagger doc name `v1` to export file. The name is version of API.
Is there a way to export the latest version?

I tried to create a swagger doc with name "latest" that contains the latest version of API but I couldn't. Do anyone know how to create a swagger doc that display the latest version of API?

Comment: I don't know about dotnet but take a look at the pet store example on editor.swagger.io

Comment: what do you mean by latest version, do you want to give new version like v2 or v3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one for help. I have found a solution.

The main goal is to avoid changing the console command when new version API appears. I am talking about the last part `v1`. If v2 doc appears, I have to pass it to the command.

Now I can pass `latest` value to the command and get rest-api.json that contains the latest version of API.

```
swagger tofile --serializeasv2 --output rest-api.json C:\Service.dll latest
```

What I did:

In my project I have implemented a decorator for the service that implements `ISwaggerProvider`

```
public class SwaggerGeneratorDecorator: ISwaggerProvider
{
    private readonly ISwaggerProvider _decorated;
    private readonly IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider _provider;

    public SwaggerGeneratorDecorator(ISwaggerProvider decorated, IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider provider)
    {
        _decorated = decorated;
        _provider = provider;
    }
        
    public OpenApiDocument GetSwagger(string documentName, string host = null, string basePath = null)
    {
        if (documentName == "latest")
        {
            var group = _provider.ApiDescriptionGroups.Items.MaxBy(group => group.GroupName);
            documentName = group?.GroupName ?? documentName;
        }

        return _decorated.GetSwagger(documentName, host, basePath);
    }
}
```

Then register it in service collection.

```
services.Decorate<ISwaggerProvider, SwaggerGeneratorDecorator>();
```

Now, when I run the command with 'latest' parameter, I get generated file with the latest API version.

Answer (score 0):

`v1` is the default name given by the code example from [the Swashbuckle project](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore):

```
services.AddMvc();

services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
});
```

It has no particular meaning as a version number beyond this - it's just what the code author has chosen to call it. The 'latest version' is whatever the code currently specifies. Calling `c.SwaggerDoc` multiple times with different names would expose different Swagger documents and you could choose to make their name indicate a version - this is down to the project's Swashbuckle configuration.